# Linux app to quickly (with auto-complete) open desired folders in a file manager

Tags: linux, open-source, file-management, directories, autocomplete

Please recommend an open-source gratis tool for Linux which provides a text input field in which the user can enter any folder (directory) name and the application will then open that folder in the default file manager.

Auto-complete is a requirement.

For example, let's say a user has the following folder structure:

```
/dev
/dev/assembly
/dev/C
/dev/perl
/dev/python
```

If the user launches this tool, and types the letter `p`, `/dev/perl` will appear.  If they then type the letter `y`, `/dev/python` will appear.  If they then press the `enter` key, `/dev/python` will be opened in their file manager.

The app needs to be fast enough to be used throughout the day; thus the folder tree may need to be cached by the app.

Although not a requirement, it will be nice if the user can define some folders to be blocked from appearing in the auto-complete results.

Ideally, the app will have an integrated option to launch it via a keyboard shortcut, but this functionality can be added via another tool, if needed.

Comment: Does it need to work as a GUI?

Comment: @Destroy666 Yes and no. More yes, but a little no. I'll explain. I'll be using this tool dozens of times per day, so I don't want to have to drop into a terminal every time to use it (or have a large intrusive terminal window open up each time, if I am not currently in the terminal).  I want to just assign this tool a quick keyboard shortcut to launch it, type a handful of characters, and press `enter` to open the desired folder.  That said, this tool doesn't need to be super pretty.  A simple text-based UI is sufficient.